# How to make a Tron like trail in Slick2D

Tags: java, video, lwjgl, slick2d

I am working on a Tron like game for my project for Grade 11 Computer Science using Slick2D. I am stuck on making the trail. How can I create the trail? If I create the rectangle, how do I colour it? Here is my code for the Game class.

```
package bmtron;

import java.awt.Rectangle;
import org.newdawn.slick.Color;
import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.Graphics;
import org.newdawn.slick.Image;
import org.newdawn.slick.Input;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.BasicGameState;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.StateBasedGame;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.transition.FadeInTransition;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.transition.FadeOutTransition;

class Game extends BasicGameState {

int stateID = -1;

// Getting the width, height and the scale from Tron.java 
int w = Tron.WIDTH;
int h = Tron.HEIGHT;
float s  = Tron.SCALE;

// Variable declaration and initialization
float player1x = (480*s), player1y = (540*s);
float player2x = (1440*s), player2y = (540*s);
int direction1x = 5, direction1y = 0;
int direction2x = -5, direction2y = 0;
boolean isDead1 = false, isDead2 = false;
boolean right1 = true, left1 = false, up1 = false, down1 = false;
boolean right2 = false, left2 = true, up2 = false, down2 = false;

// Images that are going to be used in this state
static Image gameBackground = null;
static Image player1 = null;
static Image player2 = null;

// Bounding boxes
Rectangle p1 = new Rectangle((int)(player1x),(int)(player1y),(int)(20*s),(int)(20*s));
Rectangle p2 = new Rectangle((int)(player2x),(int)(player2y),(int)(20*s),(int)(20*s));

public Game(int stateID) {
    this.stateID = stateID;
}

@Override
public int getID() {
    return stateID;
}

@Override
public void init(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg) throws SlickException { 
    gameBackground = new Image("/resources/background/gamebackground.jpg");
    player1 = new Image("/resources/images/player1.png");
    player2 = new Image("/resources/images/player2.png");
}

@Override
public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g) throws         SlickException {
    gameBackground.draw(0, 0, w, h);

    // Drawing the players to the screen
    if (isDead1 == false){
        player1.draw(player1x,player1y,s);
    }else{
        player1.destroy();
    }

    if (isDead2 == false){
        player2.draw(player2x,player2y,s);
    }else{
        player2.destroy();
    }
}

@Override
public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int i) throws SlickException {
    // Updating the location of the bounding boxes
    p1.setLocation((int)(player1x),(int)player1y);
    p2.setLocation((int)(player2x),(int)player2y);

    Input input = gc.getInput();

    getMovement(gc);
    // Checking to see if the players went out of bounds
    if (player1x>(1920*s)||player1x<1){
        isDead1 = true;
        player1.destroy();
    }else{
        player1x +=direction1x;
    }
    if (player1y>(1080*s)||player1y<1){
        isDead1 = true;
        player1.destroy();
    }else{
        player1y +=direction1y;
    }


    if (player2x>(1920*s)||player2x<1){
        isDead2 = true;
        player2.destroy();
    }else{
        player2x +=direction2x;
    }
    if (player2y>(1080*s)||player2y<1){
        isDead2 = true;
        player2.destroy();
    }else{
        player2y +=direction2y;
    }

    // Exit using escape
    if (input.isKeyPressed(Input.KEY_ESCAPE)) {
        System.exit(0);
    }

    // Checking if the two players collide with each other
    if (p1.intersects(p2)) {
        isDead1 = true;
        isDead2 = true;
    }

    // Checking who has won
    if (isDead1 == true && isDead2 == true) {
        sbg.enterState(4, new FadeOutTransition(Color.white, 1000), new FadeInTransition(Color.white, 1000));
        //System.exit(0);
    }
    if (isDead2 == true) {
        System.err.println("Player 1 has won!");
        sbg.enterState(4, new FadeOutTransition(Color.white, 1000), new FadeInTransition(Color.white, 1000));
        //System.exit(0);
    }
    if (isDead1 == true) {
        System.err.println("Player 2 has won!");
        sbg.enterState(4, new FadeOutTransition(Color.white, 1000), new FadeInTransition(Color.white, 1000));
        //System.exit(0);
    }     
}

private void getMovement(GameContainer gc) {
    Input input = gc.getInput();

    // Player 1 controls
    if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_RIGHT)) {
        right1 = true;
        left1 = false;
        up1 = false;
        down1 = false;
    }
    if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_LEFT)) {
        right1 = false;
        left1 = true;
        up1 = false;
        down1 = false;
    }
    if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_UP)) {
        right1 = false;
        left1 = false;
        up1 = true;
        down1 = false;
    }
    if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_DOWN)) {
        right1 = false;
        left1 = false;
        up1 = false;
        down1 = true;
    }

    // Movement of Player 1
    if (right1 == true && player1y % (20*s) == 0){
        direction1x = 5;
        direction1y = 0;
    }else if (left1 == true && player1y % (20*s) == 0){
        direction1x = -5;
        direction1y = 0;          
    }else if (up1 == true && player1x % (20*s) == 0){
        direction1x = 0;
        direction1y = -5;           
    }else if (down1 == true && player1x % (20*s) == 0){
        direction1x = 0;
        direction1y = 5;
    }

    // Player 2 controls
    if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_D)) {
        right2 = true;
        left2 = false;
        up2 = false;
        down2 = false;
    }
    if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_A)) {
        right2 = false;
        left2 = true;
        up2 = false;
        down2 = false;
    }
    if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_W)) {
        right2 = false;
        left2 = false;
        up2 = true;
        down2 = false;
    }
    if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_S)) {
        right2 = false;
        left2 = false;
        up2 = false;
        down2 = true;
    }

    // Movement of Player 2
    if (right2 == true && player2y % (20*s) == 0){
        direction2x = 5;
        direction2y = 0;
    }else if (left2 == true && player2y % (20*s) == 0){
        direction2x = -5;
        direction2y = 0;          
    }else if (up2 == true && player2x % (20*s) == 0){
        direction2x = 0;
        direction2y = -5;           
    }else if (down2 == true && player2x % (20*s) == 0){
        direction2x = 0;
        direction2y = 5;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Look at [java.awt.Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) class.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't worked with LWJGL or Slick 2d that much but this how to color:

```
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    Color.white(or the color of choice).bind();
    glVertex2f(x, y);
    glVertex2f(x2, y2);
    glVertex2f(x3, y3);
    glVertex2f(x4, y4);
    glEnd();
```

And I dont have a computer around at the moment to test but for the fade effect try:

```
    //call when the effect is to begin
    //If you don't have a set update rate
    counter++
    //If you lock logic update rate
    counter += 1.0f * delta

    private float r, b, g //I think opengl uses RBG, but the name doesn't matter

    public setFade(){
          //the 5 can be changed to however long you want the ribbon to stay visible 
         if(counter > 5); r-- (or r -= 1.0f * delta);
         if(counter > 5); b-- (or b -= 1.0f * delta);
         if(counter > 5); g-- (or g -= 1.0f * delta);
     }
```

where you draw the rectangle should look like this:

```
    glClearColor(r, b, g, 0.0f);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    Color.white(or the color of choice).bind();
    glVertex2f(x, y);
    glVertex2f(x2, y2);
    glVertex2f(x3, y3);
    glVertex2f(x4, y4);
    glEnd();
```

And you just draw this as chunks for the ribbon.

You can also technically achieve that effect by just never calling the glClearColor at all, but the only problem with that is that the color never gets cleared and after awhile performance problems start occurring and theres no fade effect, it only trails

Again I don't have a computer at the moment around to test this but the logic seems right and if it doesn't work then it should at least set a base for the type of logic you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, but I am looking for a trail that appears on the screen and stays. If you dont know what game I am talking about here is an example: [link](http://kryshen.net/games/bmtron.html)

Comment: Ok, then you might want to dip down into more complicated openGL methods. I know openGL has support for custom shaders, so you might want to look into that. heres a [link](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/tutorials/TyphoonLabs/Chapter_1.pdf) . I don't believe that tutorial is made for Java, but LWJGL does a good job of minimizing the differences.